# Is defaulting to an empty lambda better or worse than checking for a potentially null lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm working on a small scene graph implementation in Java 8.  The basic scene node looks something like this:

```
public class SceneNode {
  private final List<SceneNode> children = new ArrayList<>();
  protected Runnable preRender;
  protected Runnable postRender;
  protected Runnable render;

  public final void render() {
    preRender.run();
    render.run();
    for (Renderable child : children) {
      child.render();
    }
    postRender.run();
  }
}
```

This works fine if the `Runnables` default to `() -> {}`.  However, alternatively I could allow them to be null, but that means that `render()` method has to look like this:

```
  public final void render() {
    if (null != preRender) { preRender.run(); }
    if (null != render) { render.run(); }
    for (Renderable child : children) {
      child.render();
    }
    if (null != postRender) { postRender.run(); }
  }
```

So my question is, is the implicit cost of the branching introduced by the null check likely to cost more or less than whatever the JVM ends up compiling an empty lambda into?  It seems like it should end up costing more to check for null, because a potential branch limits optimization, while presumably the Java compiler or JVM should be smart enough to compile an empty lambda into a no-op.

Comment: Don't even bother checking for `null`.  Trust that Java will do the right thing with the empty runnable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If your definition of "the right thing" is to throw a NullPointerException, then yes.

Comment: I think his point was to never allow them to be null, since he's referring explicitly the the empty runnable idea.

Comment: I have to agree with Erwin.    Java supports NULL period.   It is sloppy to not check for it even with Optional.   This is a completely legal line of code.   Optional<Object>  fubar = null;    So anyone telling you that do you do not need to check for NULL is a white board developer that does not understand the real world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is defaulting to an empty lambda better or worse than checking for a potentially null lambda?

This is essentially the same as asking if it is better to test for a null `String` parameter or try to substitute an empty `String`.

The answer is that it depends on whether you *want to* treat the `null` as a programming error ... or not.

My personal opinion is that *unexpected* `null`s should be treated as programming errors, and that you should *allow* the program to crash with an NPE.  That way, the problem will come to your attention earlier and will be easier to track down and fix ... than if you substituted some "make good" value to stop the NPE from being thrown.

But of course, that doesn't apply for *expected* `null` values; i.e. when the API javadocs say that a `null` is a permissible value, and say what it means.

---

This also relates to how you *design* your APIs.  In this case, the issue is whether your API spec (i.e. the javadoc!) should insist on the programmer providing a no-op lambda, or treat `null` as meaning the same thing.  That boils down to a compromise between:

- API client convenience,
- API implementor work, and
- robustness; e.g. when using the value of an incorrectly initialized variable ...

---

> I'm more concerned about the implications of the runtime performance of using an empty lambda vs using a null and having to do a null check.

My intuition is that testing for `null` would be faster, but any difference in performance will be small, and that the chances are that *it won't be significant* to the overall performance of the application.

(**UPDATE** - Turns out that my intuition is "half right" according to @Balder's micro-benchmarking.  For a `-client` mode JVM, null checking is a bit faster, but not enough to be concerning.  For a `-server` mode JVM, the JIT compiler is *apparently* optimizing both cases to native code with identical performance.)

I suggest that you treat that you would (or at least *should*) treat any potential optimization problem:

1. Put off any optimization until your application is working.
2. Benchmark the application to see if it is already fast enough
3. Profile the applications to see where the real hotspots are
4. Develop and test a putative optimization
5. Rerun the benchmarks to see if it improved things
6. Go to step 2.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm getting at.  Sure, for a public API, the distinction between returning null and returning an empty value is, or at least can be, a decisions about the semantics of the API.  What I'm asking about here is different.    

  These fields are part of the internal implementation and it's up to me and me alone whether I want to populate 'preRender' where the client has offered no action to be taken there.  

  I'm more concerned about the implications of the runtime performance of using an empty lambda vs using a null and having to do a null check.

Comment: If you're going to demand an empty lambda, it might be a good idea to also provide something like:
        YourClass.EMPTY_LAMBDA
Or something to that effect. Make it easier to do the right thing and more people will do the right thing. Remember that people are lazy and the harder you make it to pass a null (use [@NotNull](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html#notnull) and similar if they're available) and document clearly that it's strictly verboten.

Otherwise @Stephen C says things I agree with.

Answer (score 11):

Interestingly, it seems that **checking for null is a little bit faster**, than calling an empty lambda or an empty anonymous class, when the JVM is run with the `-client` argument. When running with `-server`, the performance is the same for all approaches.

I have done a micro benchmark with [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/), to test this.

Here is the test class (latest Caliper form git necessary to compile):

```
@VmOptions("-client")
public class EmptyLambdaTest {

    public Runnable emptyLambda = () -> {};
    public Runnable emptyAnonymousType = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {}
    };

    public Runnable nullAbleRunnable;

    @Benchmark
    public int timeEmptyLambda(int reps){
        int dummy = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            emptyLambda.run();
            dummy |= i;
        }
        return dummy;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int timeEmptyAnonymousType(int reps){
        int dummy = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            emptyAnonymousType.run();
            dummy |= i;
        }
        return dummy;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int timeNullCheck(int reps){
        int dummy = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            if (nullAbleRunnable != null) {
                nullAbleRunnable.run();
            }
            dummy |= i;
        }
        return dummy;
    }

}
```

And here are the benchmark results:

- [Running with -client](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/12b55b7d-37a5-4302-a422-c76c53e842e9#r%3ascenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName)
- [Running with -server](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/9ea672c6-8645-4ede-be1b-968faecc5ef9#r%3ascenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName)

Comment: Isn't Java 7 and newer almost always running in Server Mode unless otherwise specified though?
I mean, the [64-bit version of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#options) completely ignores the -client flag, and always runs in server mode.